# Observing a question mark sign (?) on every file of a c# project after i reload the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj

Whenever I unload and reload a c# project file, i am observing '?' sign on every file of the project in VS2013 Update 5 (Ultimate Version). Even though it does not hurt me in any way as i am able to build the project in normal way, it does not look good. Also, if i close the solution and reopen it, it goes away. However, this takes time to reopen the solution which is very annoying. Has anybody seen this behavior or having some idea to resolve it.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378974/blue-question-mark-on-files-in-solution-explorer

Comment: Is the question mark at the very top of the source file?  It might be a unicode byte-order mark.  Some versions of VS are inconsistent about which files save as ascii and which as unicode.

Or did you mean you see it in the solution tree or something?

Comment: I see it on every file including the project name and it does not look like a unicode byte-order mark. As it was my first query on the stackoverflow, i am unable to upload a pic. However, i am writing an example below if it makes any sense:   ? c# csProjName, ?c# File.cs

Comment: I just discovered that when i removed the Perforce plugin from Visual Studio's Tools->Option->Source Control->Plug-in Selection and selected 'None' as the Current source control plug-in, the '?' sign is gone after i reload the project.